# Why is it that angular/typescript http GET method does not accept JSON object as parameter

Tags: json, angular, object, parameters, get

CODE SAMPLE 1

```
passJSONObj(){
  let name = 'user names',
  let email = 'useremail@domain.ext'

  return this._http.get('url?name=usernames&email=useremail@doamin.ext');
```

}

CODE SAMPLE 2

```
passJSONObj(){
let param = {
    name: 'usernames',
    email: 'useremail@domain.ext'
}
return this._http.get('url', param);
```

}

Code sample 1 works fine but code sample 2 does not. I want to know the reason. I've made research but I haven't understand why such a simple code won't work

Comment: `get` simply does not have a parameter for json data, if you need to send additional data with your request, you can for example  use `post`

Comment: @Mike thanks for your response. I know that get method does not have a parameter for JSON data. I want to know the reason behind it.

Comment: I think it's up to your Backend headers for `Access-Control-Allow` to accept and parse the data properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter is not only for "query params". So you can try something like this

```js
return this._http.get('url', { params : param});
```

See the type documentation :

```
 /**
     * Construct a GET request which interprets the body as text and returns the full response.
     *
     * @return an `Observable` of the `HttpResponse` for the request, with a body type of `string`.
     */
    get(url: string, options: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe: 'response';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType: 'text';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }): Observable<HttpResponse<string>>;
```

Comment: I've tried that before, the parameters are not seen at the backend.

Comment: if you open your navigator "dev console" can you see those parameters in the network tab ?

Comment: Yes I can see the parameters and their data in the network tab

Comment: does it look like : '...........url?name=usernames&email=useremail@doamin.ext'  ?

Comment: ok so you problem seem not to be on the angular side. What kind of backend do you have and how do you try to get those parameters ?

Comment: Thanks, its fine now, In the parameters I passed to the backend, I mistype "corporateName" for "corporatename